# Compilation error when using Streams and Maven

Tags: maven, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm having a strange compilation error when trying to compile my code with ***Maven***, my code works inside Eclipse, I am using ***Java 8*** and `Files.lines` to read a file.

```
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/nilemarbarcelos/Dev/ConferenceTrackManager/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/nilemarbarcelos/Dev/ConferenceTrackManager/src/main/java/com/nilemarbarcelos/FileInputHandler.java:[29,69] incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.122 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-03T14:26:41-03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/211M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project ConferenceTrackManager: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/nilemarbarcelos/Dev/ConferenceTrackManager/src/main/java/com/nilemarbarcelos/FileInputHandler.java:[29,69] incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

The code is as follows:

```
List<String> lines = null;
        try {
            URL path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(source);
            if (Objects.isNull(path)) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found");
            }
            lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path.toURI())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where I am using `collect()` method.

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?

Comment: The core of the problem as reported: `FileInputHandler.java:[29,69] incompatible types: java.util.List<java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.util.List<java.lang.String>`

Comment: Surprisingly, in my case this error is not fixed by setting version in compiler target. I tried with:`<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>`. So I tried with casting the stream as `newSet = oldSet.stream().map(MyClass.class::cast).collect(Collectors.toSet());` Looks like it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have your POM here, but you probably haven't [specified the JDK](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Once you've added this to the `<plugins>` section of your POM and do a `mvn clean install`, the error should resolve itself.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem

Comment: Sure, it's kind of you "accept" the answer that resolved your issue, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It looks that at your pom file is omitted `maven-compiler-plugin`.

By default Maven for `compile` stage doesn't use 1.8 version of JDK.

Comment: Thank you, you've helped  to find out what was happening.